# Linq check for null and replace null value in orderby

Tags: c#, linq

I have a linq query where sometimes the string field, product name, may be empty, null.
This is a new field in the table and if data hasn't been entered, then I get an error when running the query.  What I need to do is check for null and if null replace the null/empty value with the text value from a drop down list. I've tried several things but can't get it to work.

```
public IQueryable<Product> BindProduct([Control("ddProductName")] int? ProductNameId)
{
   var prod = from c in _DbContext.Products
      where c.ProductNameId == ProductNameId
      orderby string.IsNullOrEmpty(c.ProductName) ? ddProductName.SelectedItem.Text : c.ProductName,
      c.ItemNumber
      select c;
      return prod;
}
```

**CHANGED TO:**

```
 public IQueryable<Product> BindProduct([Control("ddProductName")] int? ProductNameId)
    {
        var prodName = ddProductName.SelectedItem.Text;
        var prod = from c in _DbContext.Products
                   where c.ProductNameId == ProductNameId
                   let sortName = c.Name ?? prodName
                   orderby sortName, c.ItemNumber
                   select new { c, sortName };
        return prod;

    }
```

**UPDATE:**
I don't think I was clear.  What I need to do is check for null and if null replace the null/empty value with the text value from a drop down list.

Comment: "I get an error" - what error?

Comment: @Servy: She (if it's not a fake)

Comment: I am definitely a she:-).  I don't think I was as clear as I should have been.  I do need to do a replace when product name is null/empty in the main query, but I also need to check it again when doing an orderby.

Comment: @SheriTrager You still haven't stated the error.  Also, to your edit, what is the result of that change?  Did it fix the problem, does it give the same error, does it give a new one, what?

Comment: I haven't been able to test the query because I have an error returning prod. Cannot explicitly convert System.Linq.IQueryable<AnonymousType#1> to System.Linq.IQueryable<Model.Product> An explicit conversion exists.

Comment: @SheriTrager You need to *say that in the question*.  It's essential to trying to solve it.  When people ask you for additional information you should provide the information they're asking for, not just repeat the unhelpful information that doesn't include what is asked for, as you did in your last edit that added nothing useful.

Comment: Yes I know, I really apologize.  I initially thought I was getting an error, but instead of the field name, I was using another table name. Moving to quick with intellisense.

Answer (score 7):

"Let" keyword should do the trick.

Here is a LINQPad example:

```
var products = Enumerable.Range(0, 100).Select(q => new {ProductNameId = 1, ProductName = (q % 15 == 0 ? null : (q % 3 == 0 ? "Fizz" : (q % 5 == 0 ? "Buzz": q.ToString()))), ItemNumber = q});
var ddProductName_SelectedItem_Text = "FizzBuzz";
var ProductNameId = 1;
var prod = from c in products
                     where c.ProductNameId == ProductNameId
                     let sortName = c.ProductName ?? ddProductName_SelectedItem_Text
                     orderby sortName, c.ItemNumber
                     select c;
return prod; //prod.Dump(); //for linqpad debugging
```

Comment: What does prod.Dump() do.  Shouldn't I just return prod?

Comment: .Dump is an extension method of http://www.linqpad.net/.
Yes, you can return prod. Just don't forget to modify select statement for production.

Comment: I update my post to show what I'm now using. What do I use to return prod?

Comment: Just change select new {c, sortName} to select c.

Comment: Thank you, it did return the query but it did not replace the null/empty name field with the drop down list value.

Comment: I think it will be pretty hard to do within current architecture. If I were you, I would either modify drop-down and do replacement on client side or create a DTO with product and sortName and bind it instead.

Comment: So it's not possible to replace a null/empty value in Linq?  I know I used to be able to do it using Linq to SQL.

Answer (score 2):

The answer came from a peer of mine, Brad.  For anyone else who is wondering how to replace a null/empty value using linq, see below.

```
public IQueryable<Product> BindProduct([Control("ddProductName")] int? ProductNameId)
{
    var prodName = ddProductName.SelectedItem.Text;
    var prod = _DbContext.Products.Where(c => c.ProductNameId == ProductNameId).ToList().Select
    (p =>
    {
        p.Name = string.IsNullOrEmpty(p.Name) ? prodName : p.Name;
        return p;
    }).OrderBy(p => p.Name).ThenBy(p => p.ItemNumber).AsQueryable();

    return prod;
}
```

Comment: It's the `ToList()` that allows that syntax, changing the query into a a LINQ-to-Objects enumeration. LINQ-to-SQL or LINQ-to-Entities doesn't know how to translate `string.IsNullOrEmpty()`, checking for null _or_ an empty string, which is different than simply a null substitution. Otherwise, that query would throw a runtime exception.

Answer (score 1):

When you call the orderby in your query, LINQ to SQL will attempt to resolve it into an order by statement in SQL. Since SQL has no method for a conditional order by statement, the method will fail to compile from LINQ.

What you want can be achieved, but it will require ordering the set client side instead of server side. My suggestion would be to run the query without the order by, and at the point that you need to order, first transform the collection to an IEnumerable collection. This will pull into memory the results from the IQueryable, and you'll be able to run the orderby against the object collection.

The basic flow will be something like this: queryable.AsEnumerable().OrderBy()

The big takeaway here is to remember that LINQ will try to transform an IQueryable into a SQL query at the point at which you request an enumeration over the collection. There is a pretty good high level explanation here: http://blog.worldmaker.net/2013/mar/11/mini-lecture-linq-visualization/.

Comment: I do need to be able to sort/add/edit/delete the records.  I am using web forms and this is being bound to a list view.

Comment: You can still sort/add/edit/delete. In fact, if you want to add/edit/delete to the collection once its been pulled from the database, you'd have to have it in a local cache anyway, which means it should be in an IEnumerable collection. LINQ works with both SQL and .Net objects. Just sort the collection after you've pulled the data from the database since the CLR has more freedom in generating the sorting delegates.

Comment: The data base can do these operations *much* more effectively than they can be done on the application side, and the value that is in the application that isn't resolved is a constant value, so while the query provider *isn't* resolving it to a constant value before compiling the query, it *can* do so, it's simply a matter of ensuring that happens.

Comment: Yes, I used to always use the db to handle all this stuff.  Just trying to learn some of the new stuff so I can eventually switch to MVC.